# Error al iniciar Android Studio en windows 10

Tags: android-studio

Al iniciar Android Studio me sale un mensaje de error, hace una semana iniciaba con normalidad, pero ahora antes de que empiece a cargar me sale este error.

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:428)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:408)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:218)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

¿Existe alguna solución o tendré que reinstalarlo?

Comment: mmm..cuando abres el android studio que aparece??cuando te sale ese error??

Comment: El error es lo único que aparece después de dar click sobre Android Studio para abrirlo.

Comment: Pero no cargas ningún proyecto ni nada??as intentado crear un ejercicio nuevo para ver si el problema es del poryecto o del android?

Comment: No her cargado nada por lo mismo que no se inicia correctamente, es decir nunca se inicia la interfaz gráfica del IDE.

Comment: @FrEqDe estas usando Xamarin o Android Studio?

Comment: @Jorgesys **Android Studio 2.3**

Comment: Aqui esta la solucion del problema. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glqAwPDg40s Sigue los pasos del comentario, si funciona. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede simplemente eliminar el cache, este error que comentas yo lo tuve pero al actualizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Grande Jorge!! que nunca nos faltes

Answer (score 1):

buenas. Yo para poder solucionar esto he desinstalado Android Studio y después he borrado dos carpetas de Android studio que se encuentra en el usuario (en mi caso Moises). En esta carpeta se deben encontrar las preferencias de inicio, del programa y otras cosas. Después he vuelto a instalar el android studio, me ha vuelto a preguntar por las preferencias de inicio (al instalar), y ya está. No se si me he explicado bien del todo, porque es la primera vez que me pasa.

Supongo que al desinstalar no borra las preferencias de inicio y la configuración, para asi poder mantener las preferencias en la siguiente instalación o por si fuera una actualización. Si el error de inicio se encuentra en las preferencias aunque se des instale volverán a aparecer en la siguiente instalación, porque se mantienen. Eso si las preferencias y no se que mas cosas se pierden, pero se puede volver a ejecutar el android.

Supongo que modificando los archivos de las carpetas que he dicho se podrán modificar las preferencias sin entrar en android studio para después volver a entrar.

Carpeta de android en el usuario ".Android"
Carpeta de Android en el usuario ".AndroidStudio2.3"

Un saludo